# excel - countif and weeknum

Tags: excel, countif, week-number

Overview

- would like to use countif and weeknum to count how many dates late on a specific week

Data
google doc> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16eTH7k7oNJcILEL8qCNKIBbg4EvkKAaRYtbN2PhfXCg/edit#gid=0

- Column 1, has dates 1/12/17(2) 1/3/17(1) 1/1/16(1)
- Column 2, has weeknum 2, 1, 1

Tried formulas:

- COUNTIF(WEEKNUM(A2:A9),A2:A9=1)
- COUNTIF(A2:A9,WEEKNUM(A2:A9)=1)

Result

- should be 2 but get 0

Question:

- what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use WEEKNUM with COUNTIF, without a helper column to do the WEEKNUM.

Use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM(A2:A9)=1))
```

Or since you already have the helper column in Column B, you can use COUNTIF on that:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,1)
```

Comment: sum product works with a constraint 2:9 but not the entire column.  throws an #value error. also i'm trying to not use a helper column

Comment: @Lacer do not use full column references in SUMPRODUCT, it will iterate through all cells one at a time.  That is 1.04 million iterations and if even one of those cells has text or an error it will through an error.  If you want full column then you will need the helper column as COUNTIF will ignore text.

Answer (score 1):

> Question:
>
> - what am i doing wrong?

The wrong syntax for [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

Answer (score 1):

Scott is right.

You can either use `SUMPRODUCT` directly or use a helper column beside and use a `COUNTIF`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM(A2:A9)=1))

=COUNTIF(B:B,1)
```

The reason to have `--` is that `SUMPRODUCT` ignores non-numeric entries. Thus we need to transfer Ture/False to 1/0.